# Unix commands to get last modified date and size of file/folder (NOT LS)

Tags: command-line, unix

I need a command that retrieves the last modified date and another that gives the size of a file.

I've looked everywhere, and I cannot find commands like this.

LS will not work.

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot use `ls`?  The underlying reason could prevent other similar commands working as well.

Comment: Because I'm parsing the command output. LS would give the right information, but the output would be ridiculous to parse.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The most common command for this is `stat(1)`. Some variants, notably GNU stat, allow specification of the output format, which simplifies parsing.

```
$ stat t.txt
  File: ‘t.txt’
  Size: 48          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 7078223     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (  500/ ignacio)   Gid: (  500/ ignacio)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2013-06-25 09:04:32.600422989 -0400
Modify: 2013-06-24 00:10:57.925679368 -0400
Change: 2013-06-24 00:10:57.970679307 -0400
 Birth: -
```