# Get Last Modified Date of File in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm new to Linux. I'm using the command-line. I'm trying to view the last modified date of a file. How do I do that in Linux from the Command Line?

Comment: `ls -l` also works...

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/612099/unix-commands-to-get-last-modified-date-and-size-of-file-folder-not-ls?rq=1

Comment: @DanielBeck is the date of `ls -l` the modified date or the create date?

Comment: @BrunoBieri It's the modification date. See `man ls`. Typical Linux file systems don't even track creation date -- see the accepted answer for the kinds of dates kept track of.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

As mentioned by @edvinas.me, `stat` tells you various information about the file including the last modified date.

At first, I was confused with *Modify* and *Change*, just to clarify, `stat` output lists:

- **Access** shows the time of last data access (e.g. read).
- **Modify** shows the time of last data modification.
- **Change** shows the time the file status last changed.

For example:

```
~ $ touch foo
~ $ stat foo
File: ‘foo’
Size: 0             Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fc01h/64513d    Inode: 410397      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (80972/ etomort)   Gid: (18429/  eem_tw)
Access: 2015-09-21 12:06:11.343616258 +0200
Modify: 2015-09-21 12:06:11.343616258 +0200
Change: 2015-09-21 12:06:11.343616258 +0200
Birth: -

~ $ echo "Added bar to foo file" >> foo
~ $ stat foo
File: ‘foo’
Size: 42            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc01h/64513d    Inode: 410654      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (80972/ etomort)   Gid: (18429/  eem_tw)
Access: 2015-09-21 12:09:31.298712951 +0200
Modify: 2015-09-21 12:09:31.298712951 +0200
Change: 2015-09-21 12:09:31.302713093 +0200
Birth: -

~ $ chmod 444 foo
~ $ stat foo
File: ‘foo’
Size: 42            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc01h/64513d    Inode: 410654      Links: 1
Access: (0444/-r--r--r--)  Uid: (80972/ etomort)   Gid: (18429/  eem_tw)
Access: 2015-09-21 12:09:31.298712951 +0200
Modify: 2015-09-21 12:09:31.298712951 +0200
Change: 2015-09-21 12:10:16.040310543 +0200
Birth: -
```

Comment: «At first I was confused with Modify and Change, but it's obvious: Modify shows time of last MODIFICATION, at while Change shows time when lastly CHANGED».

Ok, but I'm still confused...

Answer (score 98):

Use `stat` command for that:

```
$ stat file
```

Comment: If you want just the last modified date (in human-readable form), use `stat -c '%y' file`

Comment: In addition to @AdamTaylor, `date '+%F %T' -d "@$( stat -c '%Y' "$filepath"; )"`.

Comment: @ek9 I think it worths modifying your answer to include Adam Taylor's comment.

Answer (score 93):

Another way that is more flexible is using `date -r`. From `man date`:

```
-r, --reference=FILE
       display the last modification time of FILE
```

This has the advantage of allowing you to specify the output format, e.g.

```
$ date -r foo
Thu Aug 31 10:36:28 AEST 2017
$ date -r foo -R
Thu, 31 Aug 2017 10:36:28 +1000
$ date -r foo -u
Thu Aug 31 00:36:28 UTC 2017
$ date -r foo +%s
1504139788
```

Comment: Yes, very helpful, thanks.  Here is a bash function that will rename a file to be prefixed by the modified time:

    function mvfilestime() {
        if [ x"${1}" = "x" ] ; then
            echo "mvfilestime: Missing argument of file to mv"
        else
            f=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M" -r ${1})-${1}
            echo mv ${1} ${f}
            mv ${1} ${f}
        fi
    }

Comment: iso-8601: `date -r foo -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"` (works on Linux and OSX)

Answer (score 26):

`ls -l` should do the work.

Example:

```
#> ls -l /home/TEST/
total 16

-rw-r--r--   1 rfmas1   nms          949 Nov 16 12:21 create_nd_lists.py

-rw-r--r--   1 rfmas1   nms            0 Nov 16 12:35 enb_list

-rw-r--r--   1 rfmas1   nms            0 Nov 16 12:35 nb_list

-rw-r--r--   1 rfmas1   nms            0 Nov 16 12:35 nodes_ip.txt

-rw-r--r--   1 rfmas1   nms            0 Nov 16 12:35 rnc_list
```

Answer (score 11):

*Building off of* @Adam Taylor 's comment in @phoops 's answer and @Sparhawk 's answer.

To specifically *just* get the **date** (using October 3, 2019 for examples because it was my last birthday)

- `stat -c %y file | cut -d' ' -f1` will give you `2019-10-03`
- `date +%F -r file` will also give you `2019-10-03`
- `date +%D -r file` will give you `10/03/19`
- `date +%x -r file` will *probably* give either `10/03/2019`, or `10/03/19` if you're in the U.S. and either `03/10/2019`, or `03/10/19` if you're in the U.K., just to name a couple examples (of course there are more possibilities)

These `date` format options are, to my understanding, combinations of other format options. Here are some explanations from the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html):

> %b   locale's abbreviated month name (e.g., Jan)
> %B   locale's full month name (e.g., January)
> ...
> %d   day of month (e.g, 01)
> %D   date; same as %m/%d/%y
> %e   day of month, space padded; same as %_d
> %F   full date; same as %Y-%m-%d
> ...
> %m   month (01..12)
> ...
> %x   locale's date representation (e.g., 12/31/99)
> ...
> %y   last two digits of year (00..99)
> %Y   year
> ...
> By default, date pads numeric fields with zeroes.
> The following optional flags may follow `%':

> -  (hyphen) do not pad the field
> _  (underscore) pad with spaces
> 0  (zero) pad with zeros
> ^  use upper case if possible

## use opposite case if possible

N.B.: These flags don't work on the "*combo formats*" like `%F`, `%D` and `%x`. They are for the "*singular field formats*".

*Apparently this last flag (**#**) does not work as I'd expect (e.g., if `date +%b` gives `Oct`, `date +%#b` gives `OCT` as opposed to `oCT`) I guess this would be useless, but I'd think a lower case option would be more useful. `date +%#p`does turn `date +%p` which might give `PM` or `AM` into `pm` or `am`, respectively. So I guess it's not a 'per-character' case switch but sets the case of all the characters in the string to the opposite case of the majority of the characters? Also `date +%P` gives `pm` or `am`, but neither `date +%^P` nor `date +%#P` change its output. My guess for this case is that `%P` is just an alias for `%#p`, and it seems that whenever you add more than one flag, the behavior is undefined/unpredictable **(** e.g., `date +%0-e` gives the same as `date +%-e`: `3` and `date +%-0e` gives the same as `date +%0e`: `03`, which makes you think that only the flag next to the letter works or that it goes left to right, but both `date +%#^p` and `date +%^#p` give `pm` or `am`, [depending on the time of course] **)** unless there's some hidden order of operations? Sorry for digressing...*

Also, if you run the command `locale -k LC_TIME | grep ^d_fmt`, you can see the combo for the specific locale of your system (e.g., `d_fmt="%m/%d/%Y"`).

And you can make your own combo. For example,

- `date +%^b\ %-e\ %Y -r file` will give you `OCT 3 2019`

Answer (score 4):

> 1) List Files directory with Last Modified Date/Time
>
> To list files and shows the last modified files at top, we will use `-lt` options with `ls` command.
>
> ```
> $ ls -lt /run
> output
> total 24
> -rw-rw-r--.  1 root utmp 2304 Sep  8 14:58 utmp
> -rw-r--r--.  1 root root    4 Sep  8 12:41 dhclient-eth0.pid
> drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root  100 Sep  8 03:31 lock
> drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   60 Sep  7 23:11 user
> drwxr-xr-x.  7 root root  160 Aug 26 14:59 udev
> drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   60 Aug 21 13:18 tuned
> ```

https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/how-sort-files-date-using-ls-command-linux/

Answer (score 2):

If the file is on another webserver, I like [`httpie`](https://httpie.org/) ([docs](https://httpie.org/doc)).

### Installation

```
pip install httpie --user
```

### Usage

The `-h` command gives only the header. The pattern is

```
http -h [url] | grep 'Last-Modified\|Date'
```

Example:

```
$ http -h https://martin-thoma.com/author/martin-thoma/ | grep 'Last-Modified\|Date'
Date: Fri, 06 Jan 2017 10:06:43 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 06 Jan 2017 07:42:34 GMT
```

The `Date` is important as this reports the server time, not your local time. Also, not every server sends `Last-Modified` (e.g. superuser seems not to do it).

Answer (score 1):

`ls -l` shows the file's "modification time" (mtime), the time of last modification of the data in the file.

`ls -lc` shows file's "change time" (ctime), the time of the last change to the file's status information (name, path, owner, permissions).